# How to structure makefile where items are dependent on a file created by an external script?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile for a project that includes Curl, and several of our items are dependent on this Curl library.  On our platform, Curl provides its own non-Make build script that builds to a set location.  When the Curl build script is called, it only creates a new Curl library if it needs to; otherwise it exits with the existing artifact untouched.

How can I structure my project's makefile to call the Curl build script, but then only recompile our stuff if the Curl library was actually rebuilt?  I'm currently doing this, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
.PHONY: CURL.7
CURL.7:
    @cd $(CURL_PATH); sh makefile.sh
    @cp $(CURL_PATH)/CURL.7 $(TGT_DIR)
exp47: exp47.c CURL.7
```

This unconditionally calls the Curl build script (due to `PHONY` statement) and then unconditionally copies its output to our project directory.  But then 'exp47' is unconditionally recompiled.  Is there a way to invoke the Curl recipe every time but then only rebuild 'exp47' if the Curl artifact is actually recreated?

Comment: Edited the original question to fix the ".PHONY" typo (missing period).

Answer (score 1):

Note it's `.PHONY`, not `PHONY`.  If you declare `CURL.7` to be .PHONY, then it will always be run and always be considered out of date, and everything that depends on it will be considered out of date too.  Also since you're always doing a copy operation the target curl file will always be new, and since no one ever actually creates the file `CURL.7` (you create `$(TGT_DIR)/CURL.7` which is not the same thing) that rule will always run.

You can do this by putting a "buffer" rule between them, where the target only changes if the library changes.  Try this:

```
.PHONY: try-CURL.7
try-CURL.7:
        @cd $(CURL_PATH) && sh makefile.sh
$(TGT_DIR)/CURL.7: try-CURL.7
        @cp -p $(CURL_PATH)/CURL.7 $@

exp47: exp47.c $(TGT_DIR)/CURL.7
```

By using the `-p` flag in the `cp` you preserve the timestamp when you do the copy, so that if it wasn't changed by the `CURL_PATH` makefile.sh it won't be changed for you either, and that should mean that targets that depend on it won't be updated.

Note I didn't actually test this so it could be I forgot something.